# UWP Xaml, changing ContentControl's DataTemplate at runtime, Depending on the value of a property on its DataContext's

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Please I have a `ContentControl`, which displays the details of a items clicked on a `ListView`, the Item clicked is set at runtime as the Content control's `DataContext`, and I am willing to know how to change this `ContentControl`'s `DataTemplate` every time the `Datacontext` is updated, depending on a value of the `DataContext` a `DataTemplateSelector` but, the template is set only once and when the `DataContext` changes, this initial template doesn't update if it is suposed to. So, I decided to proceed by using `VisualTriggers`, but this seems not to work either, since the `DataTemplate` does not even show when I use this approach.
This is my code when I used DataTriggers:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="baseTemplate" DataContext="{Binding Selected}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Uno">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <dataTriggers:FocusDataTrigger
                                dataTriggers:FocusDataTrigger.TriggerValue="Uno"
                                dataTriggers:FocusDataTrigger.DataValue="{Binding DataContext.Type}"/>
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="baseTemplate.Template" Value="{StaticResource UnoTemplate}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Duo">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <dataTriggers:FocusDataTrigger
                                dataTriggers:FocusDataTrigger.TriggerValue="Duo"
                                dataTriggers:FocusDataTrigger.DataValue="{Binding  DataContext.Type}"/>
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="baseTemplate.Template" Value="{StaticResource detailTemplateSelector}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </ContentControl>
```

I wish to make the `DataTemplate` change `everytime` the value set to the `DataContext` has a property `Type` of value `"Uno"` or `"Duo"`
Please help!, I have tried as much as I could, but I can't find a solution for this.

I use a custom DataTrigger

```
public class FocusDataTrigger : StateTriggerBase
{
    #region DataValue
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DataValue", typeof(object),
            typeof(FocusDataTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(null, DataValueChanged));

    public static object GetDataValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(DataValueProperty);
    }
    public static void SetDataValue(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DataValueProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region TriggerValue

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TriggerValue", typeof(object),
            typeof(FocusDataTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(false, TriggerValueChanged));


    public static object GetTriggerValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(TriggerValueProperty);
    }
    public static void SetTriggerValue(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TriggerValueProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    private static void TriggerStateCheck(DependencyObject target, object datavalue, object triggerValue)
    {
        FocusDataTrigger trigger = target as FocusDataTrigger;
        if (trigger == null) return;
        trigger.SetActive(triggerValue == datavalue);
    }
    private static void TriggerValueChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        object datavalue = target.GetValue(FocusDataTrigger.DataValueProperty);
        TriggerStateCheck(target, datavalue, e.NewValue);
    }
    private static void DataValueChanged(DependencyObject target,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        object triggerValue = target.GetValue(FocusDataTrigger.TriggerValueProperty);
        TriggerStateCheck(target, e.NewValue, triggerValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are going to a wrong direction.

> Your template will change based on a property changed.

I'm not so sure what you mean here. DataContextChanged means you are switching your datacontext. But it seems here you just want to change things based on a property value, am I right on this?

Try do something with the following steps:

1. Create a DataTemplateSelector:

   ```
   public class CCDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
   {
     public DataTemplate FirstTemplate { get; set; }

     public DataTemplate SecondTemplate { get; set; }

     protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
     {
       var model = item as DemoModel;

       if (model == null)
           return null;

       if (model.ID >= 2)
           return FirstTemplate;
       else
           return SecondTemplate;
     }

   }
   ```
2. Then in your XAML you can write something like this:

   ```
    <StackPanel.Resources>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
               xxxxx
           </DataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
              xxxxx
           </DataTemplate>
           <local:CCDataTemplateSelector FirstTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}"
                                     SecondTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}"
                                     x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" />
           <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
               <Setter Property="ContentTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelector}" />
           </Style>
       </StackPanel.Resources>
   ```

In this way the template will different based on the value you set in your model.

Comment: Thankyou but, This sets the DataTemplate only once, I wish to change the dataTemplate dynamically at runtime, as the datacontext changes.